# Same webserver for Python app and php/WordPress?

Tags: python, php, webserver

I would like to use the same web server for php/WordPress content, as well as Python web application (Flask, eel, Django, WebSockets).

Here is an example:
www.myserver.com/wp/  (for WordPress)
www.myserver.com/py/  (for Python app)

I don't understand how to combine both, as these Python modules (Flask, eel, Django) usually act as a web server.

I need a solution that is compatible with major web hosting providers. Thanks

**EDIT:** I need a solution to use both on the same machine (same filesystem, same domain), but there could be 2 webserver process if there is a way they can work together.  But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: you would use apache(or nginx(i think nginx does php too?)) ... but its not that simple to just hand it to you ... and most major webhosts, are shared hosting environments without root access to install packages, and usually use thier own apache configs(sometimes you can edit them) ... but this is too broad for anyone to really answer ... but in most hosting plans this would be quite difficult i think ... unless you have vps with root and can install and manage it yourself

Comment: To use python WebSockets solutions, it looks like I need an ASGI-compatible webserver.  But Apache does not seem to support ASGI...

Comment: ahh good point ... use nginx

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I'm not sure either if nginx supports ASGI.  The documentation I see uses another webserver (Daphne) for ASGI, behind nginx